# Some question about ring of integers

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{F} = d<\infty$. If $e_1,\dots,e_d$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis in $\mathbb{F}$, there's $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such as $ne_1,...,ne_d \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$. Is it obvious that $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}[ne_1,...,ne_d] = \mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}})$?

Therefore $b \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} \iff $ there is some basis such matrix of $b \mathrm{Id} \in \mathrm{M}_d(\mathbb{Z})$ 
And how to prove that $b \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} \iff $ in any basis $b \mathrm{Id} \in \mathrm{M}_d(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Seems to me that the non-obvious fact is the existence of such $n$. If such $n$ exists (and it does), then trivially one obtains the equalities you mention: $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}[ne_1, \dots ne_d]$ since $ne_1, ne_2, \dots, ne_d$ is still a basis of $\mathbb{F}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and since $\mathbb{Q}[ne_1, \dotsm ne_d]=\mathbb{F}$ is a field containing $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$, one has $\mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}[ne_1, \dotsm ne_d]$. The other inclusion follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{ne_1, \dots, ne_d\} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not really obvious. One can use the following fact: suppose that $A$ is an integral domain with field of fractions $K$. Let $L$ be an extension of $K$. If $α ∈ L$ is algebraic over $K$, then there exists a $d\in A$ such that $d\alpha$ is integral over $A$.
As a consequence, if the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ is called $B$, and the extension $L/K$ is algebraic, we have $\rm{Frac}(B)=L$. In particular, we have
$\rm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_F)=F$ for the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=F$.

Comment: Can u explain it more widely please.
I don't see the difference between my and your statements.
pardon my eng;)

Comment: What do you want to know ?

Comment: And how to prove statements about matrix of $b\mathrm{Id}$ if we know that $\mathbb{F} = \mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}})$

Comment: I mean matrix of multiplication on $b$ in $\mathbb{F}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Comment: So why $\chi_{A} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ ($\chi_{A}$ is characteristic polynomial) only for integer $A$?
And norm and trace cover only quadratic extension?
Im sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: I fear we must stop here, but don't worry. Norm and trace are defined for number fields of any degree, and all this can be found in a book on algebraic number theory.